# WPF PreviewMouse events not working

Tags: wpf, mouseevent

Getting some strange behavior on attach to process with the code below. Each button has Mouseup and Mousedown.  On a normal run only the MouseDown works and MouseUp get's skipped.  If I put a break point in MouseUp, it still gets skipped. Put a breakpoint in MouseDown then both events work.  Any ideas or different ways?

```
private void Window_Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TelescopeHardware.Start();
    TelescopeHardware.StaticPropertyChanged += PropertyChanged;

    ButtonLeft.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += (s, ev) => { SetPulseGuideParms(0.0, -GuideRate); };
    ButtonLeft.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (s, ev) => { StartSlew(SlewDirection.SlewLeft); };

    ButtonRight.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += (s, ev) => { SetPulseGuideParms(0.0, GuideRate); };
    ButtonRight.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (s, ev) => { StartSlew(SlewDirection.SlewRight); };

    ButtonUp.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += (s, ev) => { SetPulseGuideParms(GuideRate, 0.0); };
    ButtonUp.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (s, ev) => { StartSlew(SlewDirection.SlewUp); };

    ButtonDown.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += (s, ev) => { SetPulseGuideParms(-GuideRate, 0.0); };
    ButtonDown.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (s, ev) => { StartSlew(SlewDirection.SlewDown); };

    ButtonStop.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (s, ev) => { TelescopeHardware.AbortSlew(); };

    SlewSpeed_Load();
    Version_Load();
    EquatorialSystem_Load();
    GetTrackingRates();
}
```

Here is the Xaml for one button...

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,2,2,2">
    <Rectangle x:Name="ButtonLeft" Fill="{StaticResource Arrow-Left-Bold-Circle}" Height="32" Width="32" />
</Button>
```

Comment: Don't bother with mouse down and up. Button has a Click event.

Comment: I need both events or I would have used Click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work expected if you replace the `Button` with another element that doesn't handle the mouse clicks, like for example a `Border`:

```
<Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,2,2,2" BorderThickness="1">
    <Rectangle x:Name="ButtonLeft" Fill="{StaticResource Arrow-Left-Bold-Circle}" Height="32" Width="32" />
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFDDDDDD"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF707070"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFBEE6FD"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works but does cause a few challenges making the border act like a button.